# Concatenating results in a comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to list all of the employees linked to a certain 'Interaction' I want the employees listed on one line with comma's separating them, I have the following query which works but is very slow.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(254), 
    COALESCE(
        STUFF(
            (
                SELECT 
                    ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(emp1.Full_Name,CHAR(9),''))) 
                FROM Employee emp1 WITH (nolock) 
                JOIN Rn_Int_Employee rie WITH (nolock) on emp1.Employee_Id = rie.Employee_Id
                WHERE rnint.Rn_Interactions_Id = rie.Rn_Interactions_Id 
                GROUP BY emp1.Full_Name 
                ORDER BY emp1.Full_Name 
                FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
        ,STUFF((
            SELECT 
                ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(emp1.Full_Name,CHAR(9),''))) 
            FROM Employee emp1 WITH (nolock) 
            WHERE rnint.Rn_Create_User=emp1.Rn_Employee_User_Id
            GROUP BY emp1.Full_Name 
            ORDER BY emp1.Full_Name 
            FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')))
        AS Employees    
FROM Rn_Interactions rnint
```

Does anyone have any recommendations for a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You may want to try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Post your table DDL (including indexes) and add the version-specific SQL Server tag.

Comment: efficient? Is this a time consuming query? Where's the bottle neck (look at the execution plan)?

Comment: I am not sure whether the two sub queries can be combined or not but query can be made more readable by using `Outer Apply` instead of correlated sub queries in `select`

Comment: Why the nolock hints all over the place? That is not a magic go fast button. It has a LOT of baggage with it that most people don't really understand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: This wasn't written by me, I am trying to make it more efficient .. if you think that part of it was bad you should see the rest of the query! - Thanks for the link though it will be very useful for future! @SeanLange

Comment: LOL I feel your pain. Just this part seems way overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your query and see a few interesting things:

- You are complaining about the use of `STUFF` in conjunction with `FOR
  XML PATH` as being one which is slow-performing
- You make repeated use of the `NOLOCK` hint
- Old `JOIN` syntax

I've personally had very good performance with concatenating these rows into a single cell with the use of `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` as you have done, though the issue on your end is likely a structure which can use some help. I'm willing to bet that your indexing is not up to par and that correcting those would get you really far.

Please share your execution plan so that we can point those out to you; use the following too for easy plan sharing: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Thank you - The plan is here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkhjeuPL-

Comment: What indexes do you have on `rnint.Rn_Interactions_Id` ?

Comment: I have one clustered index on the ID field

Comment: I'd imagine that the table in question is a wide one (lots of columns), correct?

Comment: You'd want to create a non-clustered index on the following two fields: Rn_Interactions_Id,
Rn_Create_User

Comment: 32 columns in this table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150324/discussion-between-eli-and-david-waldron).